# How to get and set the size of ImageButton?

Tags: android

How can I get and set the size of ImageButton programmatically?
Android seems to make button size bigger than image size.
Maybe I am wrong.
I want to make it the same size as image size.

Comment: what about using `wrap_content` for layout height and width?

Answer (score 3):

try to set padding to 0dp in xml layout:

```
<ImageButton ...
android:padding="0dp" />
```

The image should be as big as button.
If you want to make button (but not an image) transparent set button background color to @null:

```
<ImageButton ...
android:background="@null" />
```

Comment: Thanks. But, it does not work. I wrote another question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283760/how-to-place-imagebutton-at-x-y-location

Answer (score 0):

```
int height = button.getLayoutParams().height;
int width = button.getLayoutParams().width;

button.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Comment: Thanks. But, it does not work. I wrote another question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283760/how-to-place-imagebutton-at-x-y-location

Answer (score 0):

To programmatically get the height and width:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = mImageButton.getLayoutParams();
int height = layoutParams.height;
int width = layoutParams.width;
```

To programmatically set the height and width:

```
int myHeight = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.myImageAsset).getIntrinsicHeight();
/*any desired height, but for OP's sake ^^*/
int myWidth = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.myImageAsset).getIntrinsicWidth();
/*any desired width, but for OP's sake ^^*/
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = mImageButton.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.height = myHeight;
layoutParams.width = myWidth;
mImageButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```