# How to place ImageButton at x, y location?

Tags: android

I want to place ImageButton at x, y location of my view.
The problem is that Android adds padding around image.
Because I don't know exact size of padding, I cannot place image button at exact location. 
So, I want to remove padding.
How can I remove padding around image programmatically?
button.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0) makes button width shorter and height longer than bitmap.
button.getLayoutParams().width gives minus value.
What I tried so far is like this.

```
protected class MyLayout extends RelativeLayout {
    Bitmap img;
    ImageButton button;

    public MyLayout(Context context) {
        button = new ImageButton(context);
        img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img); 
        button.setImageBitmap(img);
        params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        button.setLayoutParams(params);
        params.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);
        button.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        addView(button, params);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Use this...

```
     MarginLayoutParams marginParams = new MarginLayoutParams(image.getLayoutParams());  
     int left = someValue;
     int top = someValue;
     marginParams.setMargins(left, top, 0, 0);
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams);
     image.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: but how can he set it at particular location

Comment: by using the same params.setMargins(x, y, 0, 0);

Comment: because he added it unnecessarily, if he doesnt add it in first place then he doesn't need to remove it..

Comment: I don't understand your code. LayoutParams inherits from MarginLayoutParams. Anyway that is not the problem. I want to know size of button or remove padding.

Comment: If you want to set Size of the button then use lp = new LayoutParams((int)typedDimension(50), (int)typedDimension(50)); where
 public float typedDimension(int a){
   return  TypedValue.applyDimension(
     TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, (float) a,
     getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
  }

Comment: I tried. But it has the same effect as params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: Because of padding, I cannot place image button at the place I want. So, I want to remove padding. How can I remove padding?